# Size of the image inside the ion-header

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, sass

I'm putting a background-image on my ion-header, but the image seems to be zooming

[image]

In the first image it is as it is and in the second as I would like it to be

```
.background-header {
    background: url(../img/bg_header_menu.png) !important;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I tried background-size: cover, 100% and a few more things but did not succeed

Thanks

EDIT with html:

```
<ion-header-bar class="background-header">
</ion-header-bar>
```

Sorry for the poor explanation, what happens is that the first image seems to be zooming. This way the strokes do not look the same in the second image.

And the image size is 1366x177, it's not a repeat image

Comment: looks like you want to get rid of the toggle button ?

Comment: well. it all depends on the html structure . can you please share that ? . ( HTML for `.background-header` and anything that would be relevant )

Comment: Make also snippet.

Comment: is it a repeatable pattern? Just remove the `background-size` and let it repeat like it would by default. Also, I would remove `!important` unless its really needed and change `background` to `background-image`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well. using

`background: url(../img/bg_header_menu.png) !important;` will make all the default background-properties to be important ( image, position, repeat, attachment etc  ) so the next thing you wrote , `background-size:cover`, is null because of that previous important

you should use `background-image:url(../img/bg_header_menu.png)` instead of `background`

see snippet example below :

```css
.background-header {
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/1366x177) ;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
    width:100%;
    height:177px;
    float:left;

}
```

```html
<ion-header-bar class="background-header">

</ion-header-bar>
```

OR you can use

```
 background:{url(http://placehold.it/1366x177) no-repeat scroll center center /cover transparent  }
```

if you want to use all the background properties in one style

Answer (score 0):

To assign the background-size for the ion-toolbar
this works for me

```
    ion-toolbar {
    --background: url(title-bar.png) no-repeat center / cover;
   }
```

background-size: cover CSS property doesn't work for ion-toolbar